# Can't edit crontab

Tags: cron, archlinux

I'm trying to edit my crontab, but I just can't open it!

So with my user foo, I just type:

```
crontab -e
```

Then I got:

```
no crontab for foo - using an empty one
nano: No such file or directory
crontab: "nano" exited with status 1
```

So I tried first:

```
export EDITOR=nano
```

I retried and I got exactly the same output. I also tried to set my editor to Vim with:

```
export EDITOR=vim

no crontab for foo - using an empty one
vim: No such file or directory
crontab: "vim" exited with status 1
```

But I keep getting the same output again and again. How can I open my crontab and then edit it?

Comment: do nano and vim work when you just run them by themselves?

Comment: Try to give the full path of `vim` --> `export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vi`

Comment: Yeah if I just type nano or vim (or even vi), it opens the editor. I also tried export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim and nano. Same result

Answer (score 16):

This message is normal because you still do not have any crontab for that user:

> no crontab for foo - using an empty one

Regarding the following:

> nano / vim: No such file or directory
>
> crontab: "nano" exited with status 1

It is happening because you are not defining the editor properly. To do so, you have to specify the full path of the binary:

```
export EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano
```

or

```
export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vi
```

Comment: Yeah but I also tried to set my editor with the 2 lines you gave above. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Well first check what is the path of your `nano` with `which nano`. My  `/usr/bin/nano` is just an example.

Comment: I also did it and it gave me /usr/bin/nano too.

Comment: And you are still getting the "no such file or directory"?

Comment: Yes. To summarize, I did : `EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano` `export EDITOR` `crontab -e` and I'm still getting : `/usr/bin/nano: No such file or directory`

Comment: If you use `/usr/bin/nano` in a normal basis, does it work to you? I mean, if you just execute `/usr/bin/nano`, is it opening?

Comment: Yes it does. Same with vim and vi by the way.

Comment: If you cannot use these binaries in general (not only when opening crontab), then the problem is not with crontab but with nano / vim.

Comment: And what about nano? Have you tried reinstalling it?

Comment: Yes I did. I can't understand why it doesn't work. It's not the first time I use crontab and I'm kinda sure that my settings are OK. Is it possible to create/edit a crontab file without using the command crontab -e ?

Comment: Well you can try to reinstall crontab. But I insist that if nano/vim are not working to you at all (not only on crontab), then the problem is not in crontab.

Comment: This will not work for sudo crontab -e when you need to run something on the root's crontab. For that, and a full-spectrum solution, see my answer.

Answer (score 6):

I was getting the exact same errors on my new [EC2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Elastic_Compute_Cloud) instance.

```
no crontab for ec2-user - using an empty one
/bin/sh: /usr/bin/vi: No such file or directory
crontab: "/usr/bin/vi" exited with status 127
```

Vim was working fine when you open it, but `crontab -e` was still not working. I then tried the solution:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vi
```

which did not work, and then I typed:

```
which vi
alias vi='vim'
/usr/bin/vim
```

What did the trick for me was using Vim instead of vi on the export:

```
export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim
```

Now my `crontab -e` works.

Comment: How do I make this export permanent, so that I don't have to export it with every new terminal session.

Comment: This will not work for `sudo crontab -e` when you need to run something on the root's crontab. For that, and a full-spectrum solution, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

To make **Sublime** my default editor, I started with this line in my `.bashrc`:

```
# In .bashrc
export EDITOR="subl -w"
```

The result:

```
> source ~/.bashrc
> crontab -e
crontab: subl -w: No such file or directory
crontab: "subl -w" exited with status 1
```

I tried fully qualifying the path to the soft link:

```
> which subl
/usr/local/bin/subl
> ls -la /usr/local/bin/subl
... /usr/local/bin/subl -> /Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl


# In .bashrc
export EDITOR="/usr/local/bin/subl -w"
```

The result:

```
> source ~/.bashrc
> crontab -e
crontab: /usr/local/bin/subl -w: No such file or directory
crontab: "/usr/local/bin/subl -w" exited with status 1
```

Finally I removed the `-w`:

```
# In .bashrc
export EDITOR="/usr/local/bin/subl"
```

Which worked:

```
> source ~/.bashrc
> crontab -e
# opened Sublime
```

I was able to make `nano` work using the same steps.

Answer (score 1):

Literally none of these solutions worked for me on modern [Arch Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux) when using [sudo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo).

```
sudo crontab -e # Didn't work
/bin/sh: /usr/bin/vi: No such file or directory
crontab: "/usr/bin/vi" exited with status 127

sudo -s
crontab -e # The same error

su -
crontab -e # The same issue!!!

ssh root@localhost # The same thing :O
```

Even logging in as root from the CLI (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>) didn't work...

So I was beginning to suspect it was just broken.

Well, I solved the `ssh root@` and CLI issues in both `bash` and `zsh` by adding

```
EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim
```

to the very bottom of `/etc/profile`.

I kept poking around and I found the hidden secret that's befuddling everyone here, especially [Hito's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21852141/430062)!

```
sudo visudo
```

And add the following:

```
Defaults env_keep += "EDITOR"
```

Now, it's all going to work! `sudo crontab -e`, `sudo -s; crontab -e`, etc. I bet it fixes the problem with other applications as well!

Answer (score 1):

Use the `env` program to pass environment variables to crontab.

```
sudo env EDITOR=nano crontab -e
```

It also works without `sudo`.

I haven't found a way to do it permanently, but this works.

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, you may have [nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano) installed in a different location, or in a location that isn't in your PATH variable.  As an alternative, you can try, `which pico`, and if "pico" shows up with that command, then follow the procedure of `export EDITOR=pico`, followed by `crontab -e`.

Remember to include the export line in your shell's start-up script, or the command line entered EDITOR value will go away when you leave your terminal session.

Comment: I also tried this and I still get the same output... I added export EDITOR=vim in my .zshrc

Comment: So with the 'export EDITOR=vim' in your .zshc, you are still having the problem you listed in your question?

Comment: Yes I do. I source the .zshrc and also launched a new session to be sure that it's correctly loaded. if I type `echo $EDITOR` it answers `vim`

Comment: glad you got it fixed.  I could find nothing to indicate why you had this problem.  If the editors work without crontab, then as was previously stated in the other thread, the problem must have been with your installation of crontab.  Regardless, you've got a solution working, and that's what's important.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that `/usr/bin/vi` wasn't installed. I installed it with

```
apt install vim-tiny
```

I could then access the editor with

```
crontab -e
```

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't find a fix for my problem, but I really have to be able to execute some crons. So after googling, I could find that cronie isn't the only cron manager existing. [fcron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fcron) is my solution. So I did:

```
pacman -R cronie
pacman -S fcron
```

Then instead of `crontab -e`, just type `fcrontab -e`, edit your file, and you're good. It works like a charm for me.

Answer (score -1):

My solution was to export using the absolute path of my preferred text editor in my `.xprofile`.

```
export EDITOR=/usr/bin/vim
```

I then sourced it into my `.bashrc` with:

```
[[ -f .xprofile ]] && . .xprofile
```

This will make the environment variable persist throughout every shell session.

In my case, I'm using [cronie](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/cronie/). By default it looks for `/usr/bin/vi` and produces

```
no crontab for user - using an empty one
/bin/sh: /usr/bin/vi: No such file or directory
crontab: "/usr/bin/vi" exited with status 127
```

until you set an `$EDITOR` environment variable.

Comment: It's still virtually impossible to edit the root's crontab with this partial solution. See my answer for a complete solution.

Comment: Interesting.. when I use `sudo crontab -e` with the export line noted in my solution I'm able to modify roots crontab